# Actualizar startDate de bootstrap-datepicker con la fecha actual de otro Datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap, datepicker

Estoy utilizando la libreria `bootstrap-datepicker`, en mi formulario tengo 2 datepicker y necesito que al establecer un nuevo valor para el primero, el segundo tome como startDate la fecha actual del primero

esto es lo que estoy utilizando hasta el momento:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">

    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <label>Entrada: </label>
    <input type="text" id="Entrada" class="form-control datepicker" data-provide="datepicker">
    <label>Salida:</label>
    <input type="text" id="Salida" class="form-control datepicker" data-provide="datepicker">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".datepicker").each(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#' + id).datepicker({
                uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
                language: 'es-es',
                todayHighlight: true,
                autoclose: true
            });
        });

        $('#Entrada').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev) {
            $('#Salida').datepicker({
                startDate: $('#Entrada').val()
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

pero hasta donde he podido ver, luego de que son inicializados  los componentes, no se pueden actualizar sus propiedades, que puedo hacer en este caso?

link de la libreria: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tendrias que colocar la funcion de changeDate de esta manera:

```js
$('#Entrada').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    $('#Salida').datepicker('setStartDate', $('#Entrada').val());         
});
```

Si quieres que tambien ocurra a lo inverso con la fecha de salida, puedes colocarlo de esta manera:

```js
$('#Salida').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    $('#Entrada').datepicker('setEndDate', $('#Salida').val());
});
```